# How to toggle the state of a master Checkbox using jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle

I have a list of CheckBoxes that are ALL toggled on/off by a "master" CheckBox. I am using jQuery to do this and it works well.

What I would like to accomplish is to toggle OFF the "master" CheckBox whenever any of the CheckBoxes in the list are unchecked. Likewise if ALL of the CheckBoxes are "checked" I would like to have the "master" CheckBox checked also. This way the master CheckBox is not only a means to toggle all of the CheckBoxes on/off together, but it is also an indicator if all of them are checked.

Here is my current code which toggles the checkboxes ...

```
<input id="MasterCheckbox" type="checkbox" onclick="toggleChecked(this.checked)" />

<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" class="checkboxlistitem" />
<input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" class="checkboxlistitem" />
<input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox" class="checkboxlistitem" />
```

The jQuery function

```
function toggleChecked(status) {
  $(".checkboxlistitem").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("checked", status);
  })
}
```

Any suggestions on how to get the master CheckBox to toggle based on the status of the list of Checkboxes it controls? Yipe! That is a Checkbox tongue twister.

Comment: Two wonderful examples! Thank you very much! I wish I could assign both the answer. Upvoted both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#MasterCheckbox").change(function() {
    $(".checkboxlistitem").attr("checked", this.checked);
});

$(".checkboxlistitem").change(function() {
    $("#MasterCheckbox").attr("checked", $(".checkboxlistitem:checked").length == $(".checkboxlistitem").length);
});
```

[**You can try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/7jcAC/2/)

Comment: I like this .. because if I am understanding correctly I could remove the "onclick" attribute from the MasterCheckbox element right?

Comment: Sorry, should have added in some commentary, yes that is the idea, no `onclick` attribute needed, simply bind the event handlers on `$(document).ready(...`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#MasterCheckbox").attr("checked", $(".checkboxlistitem:not(:checked)").length==0)
```

Sample Code:

```
<input id="MasterCheckbox" type="checkbox" onclick="toggleChecked(this.checked)" />  
<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" class="checkboxlistitem" /> 
<input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" class="checkboxlistitem" /> 
<input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox" class="checkboxlistitem" /> 

    <script type="text/javascript">  

        function verifyMasterCheckbox() {
                $("#MasterCheckbox").attr("checked", $(".checkboxlistitem:not(:checked)").length == 0);
        }

        $(function() {
                $(".checkboxlistitem").click(function() {
                        verifyMasterCheckbox();
                });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: do you just like double negatives?  :)  `.attr('checked', $('.checkboxlistitem:checked').length)`

Comment: Could you expound upon this a little to show where this would be placed in relation to the existing function? Having a little trouble figuring out how it is called.